# How do I stop wireless from reactivating after waking from suspend?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, suspend

In Ubuntu (Gnome) I right click on the network manager icon and untick "Enable Wireless" because I'm using Ethernet for now.

Then I suspend my Ubuntu computer.

When I wake my Ubuntu computer it starts scanning for wi-fi connections. Ubuntu has re-enabled wireless!

Any bright ideas on how to make Ubuntu honour my "Enable Wireless" settings between suspends?

Answer (score 4):

You should unset in the wireless connection the checkbox "Connect automatically" as you see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: +1 and have an image of the setting for free ;)